# Sencha GXT Grid work by name instead by index

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm trying to modify the column header menu of my grid in GXT Sencha 4.
I want to add new menu items to specific column headers.

from the gxt web site:

```
final Grid<Employee> grid = new Grid<Employee>(listStore, columnModel, new GridView<Employee>() {
    @Override
    protected Menu createContextMenu(int colIndex) {
        Menu menu = super.createContextMenu(colIndex);
        menu.add(new MenuItem("custom1", new SelectionHandler<MenuItem>() {
            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<MenuItem> event) {
                Info.display("test", "You clicked custom1");
            }
        }));
        return menu;
    }
});
```

I would like to work by column name and not by colIndex because the order of the column can change during runtime. How can I get the name of the column? And what is best practice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can search for columns in a grid using a name String. But, you can search for a column using the path:

```java
grid.getColumnModel().findColumnConfig("myValueProviderPath");
```

where "myValueProviderPath" is the value provider path.
This will retun a matching column or null if no match.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
mGrid.setView(createContextMenu(colIndex) --> {
    Menu m = super.createContextMenu(colIndex);
    ColumnConfig cfg = mGrid.getColumnModel().getColumn(colIndex);
    if (cfg.getCellClassName().equals("mycolumn")) {
       // add additional menu item
    }
    return m;
}
```

of course you need to fill cellClassName with a column name before.